# How do I load an aggregate object from db in AxonFramework or any other Event-Sourcing frameworks?

Tags: frameworks, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, axon

I've had the question for a long time. For most samples on Internet. They always creat one aggregate object first and then operate the aggregate objects. My question is, how can I load one from db other than create one every time. I'll take e-sopping as an example. I treat one product as an aggregate object. I can't load all of them into my program memory. So how can I do?

What I do is, I write another constructor whit the parameter UpdateProductCommand as well as the constructor with parameter CreateProductCommand. In this constructor, I load it from db.Is this OK?

```java
class Product{

    public Product(){}

    @CommandHandler
    public Product(CreateProductCommand command){
        apply(new CreateProductEvent(command.id));
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public Product(UpdateProductCommand command){
        load(command.id)
        ...
        apply(new UpdateProductEvent(command.id));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to use [State-Stored Aggregates](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/command-handling/state-stored-aggregates) and you can check the link for more info.

To give you some light, I would have to see which field have you marked with `@Id` and `@AggregateIdentifier` but assuming you have one `String id` (which is your `command.id` and the `@TargetAggregateIdentifier` as well), Axon is responsible for loading the Aggregate from the database based on that field. Having said that, you don't have to take care of it yourself, just focusing on your business logic (which means validations) and applying new values when needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I want. I missed this part.